# PHP calculating number of days between 2 dates

Tags: php, date

I am developing a web application which revolves around dates.

I need to calculate numbers based around days elasped, for example - pseudo code

```
$count_only = array('monday', 'wednesday', 'friday'); //count only these days
$start_date = 1298572294;  // a day in the past
$finish_date = 1314210695; //another day

$var = number_of_days_between($start_date, $finish_date, $count_only);
```

**Is there a way determine how many full days have elapsed, while only counting certain days?**

Comment: Was about to downvote for being an obvious duplicate, but you get an upvote for this one instead :)

Comment: The simplest way would be to loop through each day and count, but you could optimize it a lot by counting the number of full weeks and working out which days were the remainders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a loop which goes to the next day in the `$count_only` array, from the `$start_date` and stopping (returning from the function) upon reaching the `$end_date`.

```
function number_of_days_between($start_date, $finish_date, $count_only) {
    $count  = 0;
    $start  = new DateTime("@$start_date");
    $end    = new DateTime("@$finish_date");
    $days   = new InfiniteIterator(new ArrayIterator($count_only));
    foreach ($days as $day) {
        $count++;
        $start->modify("next $day");
        if ($start > $end) {
            return $count;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify this considerably by calculating how many complete weeks fall between the two specified dates, then do some math for the beginning/end partial weeks to account for dangling dates.

e.g.

```
$start_date = 1298572294;  // Tuesday
$finish_date = 1314210695; // Wednesday

$diff = 1314210695-1298572294 = 15638401 -> ~181 days -> 25.8 weeks -> 25 full weeks.
```

Then it's just a simple matter of checking for the dangling dates:

```
Tuesday -> add 2 days for Wednesday+Friday to get to the end of the week
Wednesday -> add 1 day for Monday to get to the beginning on the week

Total countable days = (25 * 3) + 2 + 1 = 75 + 3 = 78 countable days
```

Comment: Nice to see an answer without a loop.

Comment: Wow, that's a nice one. I'm not sure if it's correct everytime (depending on how well rounding is done), but this definitly a way to go!

Answer (score 2):

Of course there is a way :-)

The days that have been elapsed is simply

```
$elapsed_days = floor(($finish_date-$start_date) / 86400);
```

This will not get the result you need. What you could do is the following (pesudo)code:

```
$elapsed_days = floor(($finish_date-$start_date) / 86400);
for(int $i=0;$i<$elapsed_days;$i++){
  $act_day_name = strtolower(date('l',$start_date+$i*86400));
  if(in_array($act_day_name,$count_only){
    // found matching day
  }
}
```

What I do:
I iterate over every day which is between the both dates, get the day-name with date('l'); and check if it's within the array.
There may be some fine tuning need to be done, but this should get you going.

Comment: convert `$act_day_name` to lowercase and switch the incorrect order of `in_array` arguments, and I will upvote this

Comment: but if the time difference is let's say 30 years, this will make like 10k iterations... won't it kill the server ?

Comment: in_array is done, don't know how $act_day_name is not lowercase?

Comment: Well yosh, could be that it slows down the server, but I cannot think of another way other than iterating over the days, finding out if it's in the array and counting the findings. Maybe someone else comes up with a smarter solution.

Comment: @Boo `date('l')` returns first letter uppercase strings "Sunday through Saturday"

Comment: added faster solution :) find my answer please :)

Comment: also a great answer - but gave a result of 77 over salathe's 78

Comment: are you sure ? can you confirm it ? I got 78 :/ It's probably because I changed floor() to ceil() a few seconds after "commiting" first version :) so you have probably checked the "unverified" version :)

Answer (score 2):

Just a bit faster approach than "iterating through all days":

```
$count_only = array(1, 3, 5); // days numbers from getdate() function
$start_date = 1298572294;
$finish_date = 1314210695;

function days($start_date, $finish_date, $count_only)
{
    $cnt = 0;

    // iterate over 7 days
    for ($deltaDays = 0; $deltaDays < 7; $deltaDays++)
    {
        $rangeStart = $start_date + $deltaDays * 86400;

        // check the weekday of rangeStart
        $d = getDate($rangeStart);
        if (in_array($d['wday'], $count_only))
        {
            $cnt += ceil(($finish_date - $rangeStart) / 604800);
        }
    }

    return $cnt;
}
```

The idea is to count number of weeks using some additional offsets for mondays, tuesdays, wednesdays etc.

Comment: can you confirm it ? I've got 78... and seems to be right number ?

Comment: you are correct - not sure what happened there. comment deleted.